# Unable to update Object property number (counter) for counting alphabet

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and I am trying to count number of each alphabet in the `bigLettersArr`. I made a for loop to go through each element in `bigLettersArr` and update the counter, but somehow it doesn't work.  Again, all I am trying to do is to update `alphabet` object counter to get number of each leters.

Also, I think there might be much smarter way to do this, I looked up other methods for array, but was not able to find and come up with better code.

Here's my code. Thank for reading this!

```
const bigLettersArr = [ "X","E","Q","M","L","L","L","B","X","C","A","F",
                        "X","W","B","W","A","F","D","Z","B","C","L","F",
                        "M","E","B","E","A","M","L","L","B","G","L","G",
                        "H","F","H","G","M","A","F","B","B","C","G","F",
                        "H","Z","B","L","L","H","J","L"]

//made an empty array with all alphabet A-Z 
const alphabet = {
                    'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0, ... 'Z':0
                 }
             //Count how many each alphabet in the array.   
                for(let letter in bigLettersArr){
                    let targetLetter = bigLettersArr[letter]
                    // console.log(targetLetter)
                    alphabet.targetLetter += 1
                }


            console.log(alphabet)
```

Comment: use square brackets to assign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are iterables in JS. so you can simply use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop here

You should use [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop with `objects` and [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) with `arrays`

> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.-MDN
>
> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.-MDN

You can also use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) as:

```
bigLettersArr.forEach(letter => alphabet[letter] += 1);
```

```js
const bigLettersArr = ["X", "E", "Q", "M", "L", "L", "L", "B", "X", "C", "A", "F",
    "X", "W", "B", "W", "A", "F", "D", "Z", "B", "C", "L", "F",
    "M", "E", "B", "E", "A", "M", "L", "L", "B", "G", "L", "G",
    "H", "F", "H", "G", "M", "A", "F", "B", "B", "C", "G", "F",
    "H", "Z", "B", "L", "L", "H", "J", "L"]

const alphabet = Array
.from( { length: 26 }, ( _, i ) => String.fromCharCode( i + 65 ))
.reduce( ( acc, curr ) => ( ( acc[curr] = 0 ), acc ), {} );

for ( let letter of bigLettersArr ) {
    alphabet[letter] += 1
}

console.log( alphabet )
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, my problem was I didn't use square brackets to update counter...  Also, as you suggested, I changed it to for...of loop since it's from ES6!

Comment: You can also use `forEach` here. Please have a look at the Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to increment the `targetLetter` property.

Instead, use bracket notation:

```js
for (let letter in bigLettersArr) {
    let targetLetter = bigLettersArr[letter]
    alphabet[targetLetter] += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my way...

```js
const bigLettersArr = 
  [ 'X', 'E', 'Q', 'M', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'B', 'X', 'C'
  , 'A', 'F', 'X', 'W', 'B', 'W', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'Z'
  , 'B', 'C', 'L', 'F', 'M', 'E', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'M'
  , 'L', 'L', 'B', 'G', 'L', 'G', 'H', 'F', 'H', 'G'
  , 'M', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'F', 'H', 'Z'
  , 'B', 'L', 'L', 'H', 'J', 'L'
  ] 

const alphabet = Object.fromEntries(Array.from({length:26},(_,i)=>[String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0)+i),0]))

bigLettersArr.forEach( letter => { alphabet[letter]++ })

console.log( alphabet )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if non existing characters are not important you may utilize reduce straight away

```
const alphabetWithCounts = bigLettersArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
const count = acc[cur] ? acc[cur] + 1 : 1;
return {...acc, [cur]: count }
}, {})
```

more concise code

```
const alphabetWithCounts = bigLettersArr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc, [cur]: acc[cur] ? acc[cur] + 1 : 1 }), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what went wrong:

- You are using a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, this kind of loop iterates over the enumerable *keys* of an object, if you want to iterate over the *items* of an iterable (such as arrays, sets, or maps), you have to use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). In case of arrays, you get the indexes that the array has.
- The dot notation accesses fields with that literal name, if you want to access a value with a dynamic name you should use the bracket notation (`obj[name]`).

The demonstration bellow also makes use of [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```js
const bigLettersArr = []; // fill it with some values later

const alphabet = {}; //  initialize alphabet

//Count how many each alphabet in the array.
for (const letter of bigLettersArr) {
    if (alphabet[letter]) {
        // if the alphabet already has that letter we increment the count
        alphabet[letter] += 1;
    } else {
        // or else we initialize it
        alphabet[letter] = 1;
    }
}

console.log(alphabet);
```